# Argo artifact passing cant save output

Tags: docker, kubernetes, argoproj, argo-workflows

I am trying to run the [artifact passing example](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/artifact-passing.yaml) on Argoproj. However, I am getting the following error:

```
failed to save outputs: verify serviceaccount platform:default has necessary privileges
```

This error is appearing in the first step (generate-artifact) itself.

[image]

Selecting the generate-artifact component and clicking YAML gives following line highlighted

[image]

Nothing appears on clicking LOGS.

I need to understand the correct sequence of steps in running the YAML file so that this error does not appear and artifacts are passed. Could not find much resources on this issue other than [this page](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/983) where the issue is discussed on argo repository.

Comment: Have you ensured that you platform:default service account has sufficient RBAC privileges ?

Comment: Are you an admin of k8s cluster ? This command will make serviceaccount running your argo workflow a member of cluster-admin group:
'kubectl create rolebinding default-admin --clusterrole=admin --serviceaccount=platform:default' should make your serviceaccount running argo workflows  
If your are on GKE you need to first issue another command to be able to assign roles to other users.
https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/demo.md#2-install-the-controller-and-ui

Answer (score 0):

All pods in a workflow run with the service account specified in `workflow.spec.serviceAccountName`, or if omitted, the default service account of the workflow's namespace.

Here the default service account of that namespace doesn't seem to be given any roles by default.

Try granting a role to the “default” service account in a namespace:

```
kubectl create rolebinding argo-default-binding \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --serviceaccount=platform:default \
  --namespace=platform
```

Since the default service account now gets all access via the 'cluster-admin' role, the example should work now.